# use ownProps in mapDispatchToProp

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to React, just a question on passing ownProps in mapDispatchToProp, below is part of some code I saw:

```
class EditExpensePage extends React.Component {
...
}
//EditExpensePage is a component

const mapDispatchToProp = (dispatch, props) => {
    return {
        editExpense: (id, expense) => dispatch(editExpense(id, expense)),
        removeExpense: (data) => dispatch(removeExpense(data))
    };
}

connectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProp, mapDispatchToProp(EditExpensePage);
export default connectedComponent ;
```

I don't understand why we still need to pass props even it don't get used in the mapDispatchToProp function?

**Updated**:

I found that pass props in mapDispatchToProp will override user supplied props, for example,

```
<connectedComponent date={2019} />
```

so EditExpensePage components won't have props.date? is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

Its not you who is passing `props` to `mapDispatchToProps`, its being passed on by `react-redux's connect HOC` which can be useful in some ocassions

In your case you are not using `props` in mapDispatchToProps and can avoid it while defining the function

```
class EditExpensePage extends React.Component {
...
}
//EditExpensePage is a component

const mapDispatchToProp = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        editExpense: (id, expense) => dispatch(editExpense(id, expense)),
        removeExpense: (data) => dispatch(removeExpense(data))
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProp, mapDispatchToProp)(EditExpensePage);
```

EDIT:

```
connectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProp, mapDispatchToProp(EditExpensePage);
export default connectedComponent ;
```

as far as the below syntax is concerned, it is incorrect as `connect` is an HOC which takes a component as an argument whereas mapDispatchToProps need to be function references. The correct syntax is

```
connectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProp, mapDispatchToProp)(EditExpensePage);
    export default connectedComponent ;
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I can't see any differences

Comment: @slowjams, if you see you are invoking the connect HOC incorrectly, there is `)` after component which means you are passing `EditExpensePage` as a argument to `mapDispatchToProp` which is incorrect. Infact you don't have a correct syntax there

Answer (score 0):

You DO NOT have to pass `ownProps`, it is an optional argument for the case when you have to use the connected component's (container)'s own props inside the `mapDispatchToProps`. Normally you just **get** props from this map function (which props are functions) and to not pass into.

By the way the whole `mapDispatchToProps` is an optional argument. If you do not pass it to the `connect` function you will be able to reach the dispatcher from the props directly like this:

```
class EditExpensePage extends React.Component {
  handleEditExpense = (id, expense) => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch({ type: EXPENSE_EDIT, payload: { id, expense } });
  }
  ...
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(EditExpensePage)
```

Comment: It looks a minor issue, but use plural for function names: `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`. It might give you a better understanding immediately. I check your update thought soon.